# How to treat `Promise.reject` as a first-class function?

Tags: javascript, promise

Why can I do this:

```
> Promise.reject(3);
< Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: 3}
```

But not this:

```
> var f = Promise.reject;
< undefined

> f(3)
< VM2366:1 Uncaught TypeError: PromiseReject called on non-object
    at reject (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: You need to bind it to `Promise` like this `var f = Promise.reject.bind(Promise)`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko That's it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-promise.reject) defines `Promise.reject` as follows (emphasis mine):

> #### 25.4.4.4 `Promise.reject( r )`
>
> The reject function returns a new promise rejected with the passed
>   argument.
>
> 1. Let *C* be the this value.
> 2. **If Type(*C*) is not Object, throw a `TypeError` exception.**
> 3. Let *promiseCapability* be ? NewPromiseCapability(*C*).
> 4. Perform ? Call(*promiseCapability*.[[Reject]], undefined, « r »).
> 5. Return *promiseCapability*.[[Promise]].
>
> **NOTE: The `reject` function expects its
>   this value to be a constructor function that supports the parameter
>   conventions of the `Promise` constructor.**

As you can tell from this, `Promise.reject` expects to be called on a Promise constructor (either native promises or other compatible implementation). When treating `Promise.reject` as a first-class function like that, you're calling it on the global object, which is not a Promise constructor and therefore fails.<sup>1</sup>

If you need to use `Promise.reject` in this way, I'd recommend to bind it first:

```
var f = Promise.reject.bind(Promise);
f(3); // Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "rejected", [[PromiseValue]]: 3}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm not exactly sure why the global object is not considered an object, though, since `Promise.reject.call({ })` gives `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is because `reject` is defined as a static function on the Promise object.

As such, you cannot call it as you have above, as it is called directly on the class and not on an instance of the class.

More detail about static functions and when they can and cannot be called here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

You could wrap it in a function:

```
function promiseReject(x) {
   return Promise.reject(x);
}

var f = promiseReject;

var out = f(3);
```